# Top is showing % CPU > 100?

Tags: linux, command-line, cpu-usage, top

`top` is showing several processes with CPU % greater than 100%. What does this indicate?

Comment: Very 1337 Overclocking. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That the processes are multithreaded and running on multiple cores, and are busying out each core to a percentage that adds up to more than 100%.